# Python3 - Database sqlite3 - sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column:

Tags: python-3.x, database, sqlite

I am trying to create a small and simple accountancy program, here is my code:

```
import sqlite3 as lite #db
import sys #db
from pathlib import Path #check file exists

successful_login = False

def login_process():
    print("Welcome to your accountance program, write your username: ")
    user = input()
    my_file = Path("./%s" % (user,))

    if my_file.is_file():
        con = lite.connect(user)
        main_loop()

    else:
        con = lite.connect(user)
        print("Write the name of your bank account: ")
        bankaccount = input()
        print("Write how much money do you have on it: ")
        starting_money = int(input())
        print(starting_money)

        with con:
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Bank(Name TEXT, Money INT)")
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO Bank VALUES (%s,%s)" %  (bankaccount,starting_money))
        main_loop()
```

And here is the error:

[image: ,]

Why is this happening ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

From the python [sqlite API doc](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/sqlite3.html):

> ```
> # Never do this -- insecure!
> symbol = 'RHAT'
> c.execute("SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol = '%s'" % symbol)
> ```

(And examining this INSECURE example *carefully* should illuminate what is the error in this program).

Suggest you use the doc to learn how to use **placeholders**. It is an important habit to develop.